# How to check each element of a data frame for NA and print their position individually (not as a vector)

Tags: r

I'm trying to give an automated report of NAs in a data frame:

```
#####create data frame

expl_data1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(NA, 7, 8, 9, 3), 
                         var2 = c(4, 1, NA, NA, 4), 
                         var3 = c(1, 4, 2, 9, 6), 
                         var4 = c("Hello", "I am not NA", NA, "I love R", NA)) 


#####check each element for NA
out<-apply(is.na(expl_data1), 2, which) 


####print a message with the NA's position

for (i in 1:length(out)){
  if (out[i] != "integer(0)"){
print(paste("Please remove missing values from ",names(out[i]), ", line ", out[i], sep= ""))
  }
}
```

What is printed:

```
> [1] "Please remove missing values from var1, line 1" 

> [1] "Please remove missing values from var2, line 3:4" 

> [1] "Please remove missing values from var4, line c(3, 5)"
```

The output is fine if there is only one NA in the column. ButI'm not happy with the output for multiple NAs. How can I access and print the positions individually? What I want is

```
> [1] "Please remove missing values from var1, line 1"
 
> [1] "Please remove missing values from var2, line 3" 

> [1] "Please remove missing values from var2, line 4" 

> [1] "Please remove missing values from var4, line 3"

> [1] "Please remove missing values from var4, line 5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one vectorized way to do this :

```
mat <- which(is.na(expl_data1), arr.ind = TRUE)
sprintf('Please remove missing values from %s, line%d', 
        names(expl_data1)[mat[, 2]], mat[, 1])

#[1] "Please remove missing values from var1, line1"
#[2] "Please remove missing values from var2, line3"
#[3] "Please remove missing values from var2, line4"
#[4] "Please remove missing values from var4, line3"
#[5] "Please remove missing values from var4, line5"
```

---

To correct your attempt you can use `[[` instead of single `[`. `out[i]` returns a list whereas `out[[i]]` returns a vector. You can check length of output and not the text `'integer(0)'`.

```
for (i in 1:length(out)){
  if(length(out[[i]])) {
    print(paste("Please remove missing values from ",
          names(out[i]), ", line ", out[[i]], sep= ""))
  }
}

#[1] "Please remove missing values from var1, line 1"
#[1] "Please remove missing values from var2, line 3"
#[2] "Please remove missing values from var2, line 4"
#[1] "Please remove missing values from var4, line 3"
#[2] "Please remove missing values from var4, line 5"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very easy solution and thanks for providing a more elegant alternative to the instances where there were no NAs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arr.ind` from `which` to get index of rows and columns:

```
na_pos <- which(is.na(expl_data1), arr.ind = TRUE)
paste("Please remove missing values from row", apply(na_pos, 1, paste, collapse = ", line "))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to apply your solution like this:
for (i in 1:length(out)){
  if(length(out[[i]])) {
print(paste("Please remove missing values from row", apply(na_pos, 1, paste, collapse = ", line ")))
  }
}

But for some reason it prints the text three times. Do you know what's happening here?

Comment: Not need to do a loop. I don't use `out variable`. You don't use `i` variable in loop so you print same thing at each iteration.

Comment: Oh I see. Instead of a loop, "apply" applies the which function on each row! This is a good answer too, thanks.